# How do I get Rllib to use the GPU on my MacBook Pro?

Tags: gpu, apple-silicon, rllib

I have a MacBook Pro with the Apple M3 Pro chip running OS X 14.1.2. I am using RLlib to train reinforcement learning models, following the [Getting Started with RLlib](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/rllib/rllib-training.html) instructions. I want to use the GPU in this machine for training but I can't figure out how to do this.

I have both tensorflow and torch installed, and both can see the GPU.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.list_physical_devices()    
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'),
PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]

import torch
torch.backends.mps.is_available()
True
```

I am running the following command

```
rllib train --algo DQN --env CartPole-v1 --stop '{"training_iteration": 30}'
```

This trains a model, but I see the following line in the output

```
Logical resource usage: 1.0/12 CPUs, 0/0 GPUs
```

and Activity Monitor shows no GPU being used for this process.

I tried adding a `--ray-num-gpus 1` to this command. The output now reads

```
Logical resource usage: 1.0/12 CPUs, 0/1 GPUs
```

but Activity Monitor still shows no GPU usage.

How do I get RLlib to use my laptop's GPU during training?